# Use sql and php to echo an article

Tags: php

Is there a way I could use php to echo the following HTML and replace the H2 text and P text with the results stored in sqlquery?

```
<article class="frEvent" onclick="loadPopup('#frpopup1')"> <!-- Documented within the linked script file. -->
    <h2 class="frEventHeadline">FR Event</h2>
    <hr class="frEventDivider">
    <p class="frEventTagLine">25/12/2012</p>
</article>

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM frEvents WHERE date >= DATE(now());";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('error getting service listings');
```

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would recommend regex. str_replace() is also an option. Please let us know what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not here to hand you solutions for free, the community survives because everyone does an effort on their own first :)

Comment: Read [String concatenation in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc).

Comment: Hi, I understand the need for my own research but I really had no where to start. Anyway after taking advise and trying a few things this morning the final code looks like this...

Comment: <section id="fundraiserevents"><br>
<?php
$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM frEvents WHERE date >= DATE(now()) LIMIT 5;";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('error getting service listings');

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  echo '
  <article class="frEvent"onclick="loadPopup(\'#frpopup'.$row['eventID'].'\')">
 <h2 class="frEventHeadline">'.$row['Name'].'</h2>
 <hr class="frEventDivider">
 <p class="frEventTagLine">'.$row['date'].'</p>
 </article>';
  }
?>
</section>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this as next part of your code:

```
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
  echo '
   <article class="frEvent" onclick="loadPopup(\'#frpopup'.$row['yoursidrow'].'\')">
     <h2 class="frEventHeadline">'.$row['yourseventrow'].'</h2>
     <hr class="frEventDivider">
     <p class="frEventTagLine">'.$row['yoursdaterow'].'</p>
   </article>';
}
```

Comment: And the result is a parse error. You need to fix your quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I don't know why but the while statement did not work until I changed it to:    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC))    The page just refused to load until I made the change.